# Refresh DIV only every 5 seconds with JavaScript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh

I have been googling about this issue for my messaging system with PHP and MySQL.  I cannot work out how to refresh just the div that contains the messages so it can be updated every five seconds without using jquery or AJAX.  I don't want to use these because I want the website to be compatible with pretty much anything (i.e. phone, tablet, computer even e-reader browser).

Is it possible to do this with HTML, PHP or JavaScript, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using `php` to get content from back end. You can use `$('#idOfdiv').load("somePHPscriptToUpdateDiv.php")` inside `setTimeOut(function(){},5000)`

Comment: Could I replace '.load("somePHPscript... with a previously-declared function to fetch messages

Comment: If you want to send parameters to the php script to fetch messages, then i think it would be better to use $.ajax().

Comment: isn't that $ jquery though

Comment: I would suggest you to use jquery-ajax.Its pretty straight forward. Its just asynchronous javascript. For more help plz go through the link.[link] http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: OK, I'll try that, but now I have a stupid question - what would be the contents of somePHPscriptToUpdateDiv.php?  I have a function to fetch conversation messages and I've put that in (taken out the function, just inserted the code) but that doesn't work

Comment: somePHPscriptToUpdateDiv.php shound output the text you want in the `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `iframe` with reloading to a url to a PHP page to get that effect without AJAX. I don't think `iframe` is more supported than AJAX, though.

Comment: So you think I should use AJAX?

Comment: On google, the only ways I can find of doing it with AJAX (I can't work them out myself because I have never coded in AJAX before) also involve jquery.  Is there a way that doesn't?

Comment: Sure, you can use `XMLHttpRequest` directly. The reason most use jQuery is because it's simpler and it is consistent cross browsers.

Comment: It would still be best in terms of compatibility to use XMLHttpRequest directly?

Comment: so how would I implement XMLHttpRequest directly for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think so. JQuery is supported by most browsers (make sure to use the 1.x version to support IE 6, 7 and 8). Old versions of browsers are not supported (except IE) but they are uncommon.

Comment: OK, so is it supported by mobile browsers (e.g. opera mini)

Comment: Yes, jQuery is supported by mobile browers.

Comment: Ok, I'll try using it then